# cxFreeze error: resource_filename() only supported for .egg not .zipp

Tags: compiler-errors, wxpython, mysql-python, cx-freeze

I have a fully working wxpython based application, written all in Python.
I wanted to make an exe, so I used cxFreeze.

During the build, there are many modules which seem to be missing, which sometimes should not make a problem, but when I run the application it gives me an error from MySQLdb module:

```
NotImplementedError: resource_filename() only supported for .egg not .zip
```

I have a .egg for MySQL at Python 2.7 / Lib / Site-Packages.

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem in the future:

1. Go to your python directory and then to the site-packages, 
   for me was C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
2. Create a new folder and make a copy of your MySQLdb egg file there just to save it in any case you might need to recover it later. (ex MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-win32.egg)
3. rename MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-win32.egg to MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-win32.zip and unzip it in place.
4. add .egg to the unzipped folder

This worked for me with cxfreeze. Now my executable is running.

Comment: You can also use `easy_install -Z <filename_of.egg>` to let python do the unpacking for you (uninstall the package first).