# cxfreeze with scapy - only supported for .egg not .zip

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm trying to use cxfreeze with a script that contains scapy.  The compilation works just fine but when I try to execute the app I'm getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "app.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy-2.3.1-py2.7.egg/scapy/all.py", line 16, in <module>
    from arch import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy-2.3.1-py2.7.egg/scapy/arch/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from bsd import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy-2.3.1-py2.7.egg/scapy/arch/bsd.py", line 12, in <module>
    from unix import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy-2.3.1-py2.7.egg/scapy/arch/unix.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pcapdnet import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy-2.3.1-py2.7.egg/scapy/arch/pcapdnet.py", line 27, in <module>
    import pcap
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/egg/pcap.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/egg/pcap.py", line 4, in __bootstrap__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1161, in resource_filename
    self, resource_name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1854, in get_resource_filename
    "resource_filename() only supported for .egg, not .zip"
NotImplementedError: resource_filename() only supported for .egg, not .zip
```

Can someone tell me what I could do to fix this?

Here is my setup.py

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['app.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Comment: What does your setup.py file look like? Could you edit your post to include that?

Comment: @Anthony - I've added my setup.py, nothing special here, first time using cxfreeze so not too sure where to go from here.

Comment: I think I found a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872134/cxfreeze-error-resource-filename-only-supported-for-egg-not-zipp). This may be the solution.

Comment: @Anthony thanks for the link, looking at the directions though not sure I completely understand it.  It appears I rename scapy.egg to scapy.zip and then unzip it and then add .egg extension to it?  1) changing the extension doesn't automatically make it a zip file i would have to archive it on os x and 2) Creating a zip and then unzipping it brings me back to square 1.  Any idea where I'm going wrong here ?

Comment: Perhaps try the easy_install method mentioned in the comment there, but I don't know if that will change anything. Otherwise I am also at a loss. Good luck!