# Py2exe NotImplementedError: resource_filename() only supported for .egg, not .zip

Tags: python, compiler-errors, py2exe

I am trying to convert a python file into an executable and for that I'm using `py2exe`. When running the setup.py script to generate the dist folder and the executable file everything goes well. 
What goes wrong is that when I'm running the executable the following error message gets displayed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "q400.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "SUAVE\__init__.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "SUAVE\Plugins\__init__.pyc", line 11, in <module>
  File "SUAVE\Plugins\load_plugin.pyc", line 37, in load_plugin
  File "SUAVE\Plugins\pint\__init__.pyc", line 23, in <module>
  File "SUAVE\Plugins\pint\unit.pyc", line 423, in __init__
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.pyc", line 1171, in resource_filename
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.pyc", line 1872, in get_resource_filename
NotImplementedError: resource_filename() only supported for .egg, not .zip
```

When I check the file `unit.pyc` at line 423 the code is:

```
 data = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, 'default_en.txt')
```

And when I check the library.zip in the dist folder there is no `default_en.txt` file, however, it *is* present in the site-packages module.
So is it because this file is a txt file that this error shows up? 
I tried to force `py2exe` to import it but with no success. 
Also I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872134/cxfreeze-error-resource-filename-only-supported-for-egg-not-zipp) but the answer can't be applied in my case because I don't have any egg nor zip files implicated in the error (at least in my opinion).

Thank you